# Enabling download popup in my application to download files

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, download

Hi in my groovy/grails application i want to enable download popup... on clicking download button like in browsers it shoul display popup menu asking download options how can i do it...

Comment: What options do you need? Do you already know how to open a popup by javascript?

Comment: no... i will appreciate if u tell that procedure using jquery/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As about opening new window it would be something like a:

```
<g:script>
function showDownloadOptions() {
  window.open("${g.createLink(controller: 'download', action: 'options')}", "Download Options", "");
}
</g:script>
```

you can read more info about opening popup there: http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm